# Non-decreasing list of lists in Scheme?

Tags: list, sorting, recursion, scheme, partitioning

We need a Scheme function called `nondecreaselist`, which takes in a list of numbers and outputs a list of lists, which overall has the same numbers in the same order, but grouped into lists that are non-decreasing.

For example, if we have input `(1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 4 3 2 1)`, the output should be:

`((1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4) (1 1 1 2) (1 1) (0 4) (3) (2) (1))`

How would you implement this? I know we have to use recursion.
My attempt so far:

```
(define (nondecreaselist s) 
  (cond ((null? s) '())
        ((cons (cons (car s)
                     ((if (and (not (null? (cadr s)))
                               (not (> (car s) (cadr s))))
                          ((cadr s))
                          ('()))))
               (nondecreaselist (cdr s))))))
```

However, this gives me the error:

> *(int) is not callable:*

Comment: @HiThisIsMe: sorry, but this platform aims to *keep questions* to help future visitors. When you signed up you agreed to the terms and conditions, which include that you licensed the question to the site. With an answer below, you can't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define decrease-list
  (lambda (l)
    ((lambda (s) (s s l cons))
     (lambda (s l col)
       ;; limitcase1: ()
       (if (null? l)
           (col '() '())
           ;; limitcase2: (a1)
           (if (null? (cdr l))
               (col l '())
               (let ((a1 (car l)) (a2 (cadr l)))
                 ;; limitcase3: (a1 a2)
                 (if (null? (cddr l))
                     (if (>= a2 a1)
                         (col l '())
                         (col (list a1) (list (cdr l))))
                     ;; most usual case: (a1 a2 ...)
                     (s s (cdr l)
                        (lambda (g l*)
                          (if (>= a2 a1)
                              (col (cons a1 g) l*)
                              (col (list a1) (cons g l*)))))))))))))

1 ]=> (decrease-list '(1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 4 3 2 1))
;Value: ((1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4) (1 1 1 2) (1 1) (0 4) (3) (2) (1))
```

I did not comment it, if you have questions you can ask but I think you can also study yourself the code I wrote for you now.

Note also that one can consider the limit cases `()` and `(a1)` out of the loop and check these cases only once:

```
(define decrease-list
  (lambda (l)
    ;; limitcase1: ()
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        ;; limitcase2: (a1)
        (if (null? (cdr l))
            (list l)
            ((lambda (s) (s s l cons))
             (lambda (s l col)
               (let ((a1 (car l)) (a2 (cadr l)))
                 ;; limitcase3: (a1 a2)
                 (if (null? (cddr l))
                     (if (>= a2 a1)
                         (col l '())
                         (col (list a1) (list (cdr l))))
                     ;; most usual case: (a1 a2 ...)
                     (s s (cdr l)
                        (lambda (g l*)
                          (if (>= a2 a1)
                              (col (cons a1 g) l*)
                              (col (list a1) (cons g l*)))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the posted code. There is no test expression in the second `cond` clause; there are too many parentheses around the `if` and its clauses. Perhaps the most significant problem is that the code is attempting to build a non-decreasing list, which is to be `cons`ed to the result of `(nondecreaselist (cdr s))`, but when the non-decreasing sequence is more than one number long this starts again too soon in the input list by going all the way back to `(cdr s)`.

### Fixing Up OP Code

The logic can be cleaned up. OP code already is returning an empty list when input is an empty list. Instead of testing `(null? (cadr s))` (when `(cdr s)` is `'()`, `cadr` won't work on `s`), one could test `(null? (cdr s))` before code attempts a `(cadr s)`. But it is even better to move this logic; when the input list contains one element, just return a list containing the input list: `((null? (cdr s)) (list s))`.

Instead of `(and (not (> ;...` the logic can be made more clear by testing for `>` and executing the appropriate action. In this case, when `(> (car s) (cadr s))` a new sublist should be started, and `cons`ed onto the list of sublists that is the result returned from `nondecreaselist`.

Otherwise, `(car s)` should be added to the first sublist in the result returned from `nondecreaselist`. To accomplish this, we need to construct the return list by `cons`ing `s` onto the first sublist, and then `cons`ing that new sublist back onto the `cdr` of the list of sublists that is the result returned from `nondecreaselist`.

Here is some revised code:

```
(define (nondecreaselist s) 
  (cond ((null? s) '())
        ((null? (cdr s)) (list s))
        ((> (car s) (cadr s))
         (cons (list (car s))
               (nondecreaselist (cdr s))))
        (else
         (let ((next (nondecreaselist (cdr s))))
           (cons (cons (car s)
                       (car next))
                 (cdr next))))))
```

### Using a Helper Function

Another approach would be to define a helper function that takes an input list and an accumulation list as arguments, returning a list of lists. The helper function would take numbers from the front of the input list and either add them to the accumulator, creating a non-decreasing list, or it would `cons` the accumulated non-decreasing list to the result from operating on the rest of the input.

If the input `lst` to the helper function `ndl-helper` is empty, then a list containing the accumulated non-decreasing list `sublst` should be returned. Note that `sublst` will need to be reversed before it is returned because of the way it is constructed, as described below.

If the accumulator `sublst` is empty, or if the next number in the input list is greater-than-or-equal-to the largest number in the `sublst`, then the next number should simply be added to the `sublst`. By `cons`ing the number onto the front of `sublst`, only the `car` of `sublst` needs to be checked, since this will always be the largest (or equal to the largest) value in `sublst`. But, since `sublst` is in reverse order, it will need to be reversed before adding it to the growing list of lists.

Otherwise, `lst` is not empty, and `sublst` is not empty, and the next number in the input list is less than the largest number in `sublst`. Thus, a new sublist needs to be started, so the old `sublst` is reversed and `cons`ed onto the result of the remaining computation done by calling the helper function on the remaining `lst` with an empty accumulator `sublst`:

```
(define (nondecreaselist-2 lst)
  (define (ndl-helper lst sublst)
    (cond ((null? lst) (list (reverse sublst)))
          ((or (null? sublst)
               (>= (car lst) (car sublst)))
           (ndl-helper (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) sublst)))
          (else
           (cons (reverse sublst) (ndl-helper lst '())))))
  (ndl-helper lst '()))
```

Both functions work:

```
> (nondecreaselist '(1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 4 3 2 1))
((1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4) (1 1 1 2) (1 1) (0 4) (3) (2) (1))
> (nondecreaselist-2 '(1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 4 3 2 1))
((1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 4) (1 1 1 2) (1 1) (0 4) (3) (2) (1))
```